# How do I run following cmd command in python without error?

Tags: python, networking, cmd

I try to get network adapter name (e.g "Ethernet") in python.
The only way I found and works is by entering

```
for /F "skip=3 tokens=3*" %G in ('netsh interface show interface') do echo %H
```

in the windows CMD.So I tried following:

`os.system("for /F \"skip=3 tokens=3*\" %G in (\"netsh interface show interface\")")`

But it gives Syntaxerror even tho I fixed the string quote stuff...
Subprocess module not working either.
Anybody has an idea?

Comment: I would just `result = subprocess.check_output(["netsh", "interface", "show", "interface"])`, and then perform any post-processing in python. Don't have access to a windows system to test, otherwise I would leave a more complete answer.

Comment: This not only prints me the network adapter, it prints a whole table with elements. Can you add me on discord? Temal#5222

Comment: [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is deprecated since many years and should not be used anymore in new coded Python scripts. One reason is that on Windows is executed `%ComSpec% /c` using the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with the command line written in the Python script appended as additional arguments. The environment variable reference `%ComSpec%` expands on Windows usually to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`.

Comment: `ComSpec` is a predefined __system__ environment variable and is defined by default with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`. The Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` requires a special syntax for the argument(s) (command line) after option `/c` as explained in help output on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?`. Most Python programmers don't know that and for that reason their approach running the Windows command processor with a command line to execute with `os.system()` fails. There should be used the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: The `subprocess module` is on Windows a Python wrapper module for `CreateProcess` called without or with a [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure. The usage of the `subprocess module` gives the Python programmer the full control over the execution of an executable which `os.system()` does not because of `cmd.exe` is limited in its options on how it uses `CreateProcess` to run an executable like `%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe`.

Comment: The command line `for /F "skip=3 tokens=3*" %G in ('netsh interface show interface') do echo %H` works on running it from within a command prompt window, i.e. executed by an already running `cmd.exe`. There is executed by `cmd.exe` in background one more `cmd.exe` with using option `/c` and append the command line within `'` as additional arguments. So there is used `CreateProcess` to run one more `cmd.exe` which uses `CreateProcess` to run `netsh.exe` to output data to handle `stdout` of the background `cmd.exe` which is captured by the `cmd.exe` executing `for` and is processed finally.

Comment: So what you try is running `cmd.exe` with `CreateProcess` to run `cmd.exe` with `CreateProcess` to run `netsh.exe` with `CreateProcess` to output data to handle `stdout` of second `cmd.exe` process captured by first `cmd.exe` process with skipping the first three lines of captured output and output from the remaining lines just the interface name (fourth string value) to handle `stdout` of first `cmd.exe` process which should be captured by `python.exe` for further processing. Do you see how inefficient this attempt is to get the network interface names?

Comment: That very inefficient solution would even work on coding the command line correct in Python script, but you decided to change the command line to `for /F "skip=3 tokens=3*" %G in ("netsh interface show interface")` by replacing the two `'` by `"` and omitting `do echo %H`. Try this command line in a command prompt window and `cmd.exe` tells you the syntax error - `do` and a command is missing. The usage of `"` instead of `'` results in interpreting `netsh interface show interface` as string to process and not as command line to execute with one more `cmd.exe` and process the captured output.

Comment: What would be better? There is used [os.environ["SystemRoot"\]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) to get the path to the Windows directory and use the string `"C:\\Windows"` if `null` is returned because of the environment variable `SystemRoot` does __very unlikely__ not exist at all. The Windows directory path is concatenated next with the string `"\\System32\\netsh.exe"` to get the fully qualified file name of the executable to run. Next `subprocess.run()` is used with this file name string and the other three arguments `interface show interface` and capturing `stdout`.

Comment: The captured output of `stdout` is next processed by the Python script with Python code. The processing starts with fourth line from which just the string after third series of spaces up to end of line is kept for further usage. The same is done also for the remaining lines of the captured output. Python is a much more powerful script interpreter than `cmd.exe` and therefore processing the captured output with the appropriate string methods of Python should be really no problem even for a beginner in Python script coding.

Answer (score 0):

You're having trouble with the `, shell=True` [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) argument.
You don't want to see `bash` trying to
interpret that command.

Put the long command into `ether.bat` so you won't be
distracted by quoting issues, and can focus on
whether `bash` or `cmd.exe` are running your batch file.

This should suffice:

```
os.system('cmd ether.bat')
```

though it's better to use this interface:

```
interface = subprocess.check_output(['cmd', 'ether.bat'])
```

---

Python offers perfectly good text parsing facilities.
Consider dispensing with cmd.exe
and just run `netsh interface show interface`,
with a python loop that makes sense of the
returned text.